# Flexbox или CSS Grid?

Tags: css, grid

Уже давно я использую технологию flexbox, всем доволен и все работает. Но в последнее время все слышу про CSS Grid. Некоторые говорят, что CSS Grid созрел и превосходит во многих тонкостях flexbox, другие же удтверждают обратное. И у меня всплывает такой вопрос: Что же на самом деле лучше Flexbox или CSS Grid?

Comment: Не буду что-то сочинять, держите статью в которой всё подробно расписано и показано на примерах: [Статья](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-css-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-grid-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-flexbox-8fee99ab6cbd)

Comment: То, что лучше подходит для вашей задачи, ваш кэп

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Если рассматривать кроссбраузерность, то `flex` не намного, но обходит `grid`:

   [caniuse.com / css-grid](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   [caniuse.com / flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. По возможностям `flex` больше подходит для отдельных блоков и выравнивания внутри них - *по большому счету работает в одном измерении*, в то время как `grid` имеет более гибкий функционал и позволяет `работать в 2-х измерениях по оси X и по оси Y`.

   Более подробно и с наглядными примерами в статьях:

   - [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/css-grid-i-flexbox-sravnenie-na-praktike)
   - [medium.com](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-css-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-grid-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-flexbox-8fee99ab6cbd)

   ---

   И если простыми словами:

   **Grid** - инструмент позиционирования основных блоков страницы.

   **Flexbox** - инструмент позиционирования элементов внутри блоков, расположенных с помощью Grid.

   Т.е. **Grid** можно использовать совместно с **Flexbox**.

---

**Ответ на вопрос:**

> что лучше Flexbox или CSS Grid?

И **Flexbox** и **Grid** по отдельности и вместе прекрасно подходят для современной верстки макетов!