# Расстояние между элементами в CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, css-grid

Как сделать так, чтобы элементы разошлись на всю ширину контейнера без использования `grid-column-gap`?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bap9ftoq/3/)

Comment: Связанный: [Расположение блоков в Grid CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/926319/262779)

Comment: `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 50px;` Вычисление свободного пространства происходит только после применения фиксированных значений

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Единица `fr` позволяет вам настраивать размер треков как часть свободного пространства в контейнере.

```
.container {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Свободное пространство высчитывается после вычисления всех фиксированных элементов. В этом примере, общее количество свободного пространства для единиц `fr` не будет включать в себя `50px`.

```
.container {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 50px;
}
```

**Код:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**Пример 2** для родителя большей ширины и для большего кол-ва `item`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Источники:**

- [xsltdev.ru](https://xsltdev.ru/css/grid-template-columns/)
- [css-live.ru](http://css-live.ru/articles/znakomstvo-s-css-grid-layout.html)

---

**P.S:** Если же нужно выравнивание по центру, слева, справа, то можно применить `justify-items: center | start | end;`. Больше на [alligator.io](https://alligator.io/css/align-justify/).

+[Доп. ссылка на ответ о grid и flex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/925588/212421). Смысл в том, что `grid` можно использовать совместно с `flex`.

Answer (score 0):

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));`

Код:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue
}
.item:last-child{
  margin-right:0;
}
.item:nth-child(2){
margin-left:calc(50%-75px);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: На flexbox понятно как сделать, я осваиваю grid, и хочу разобраться в этом.

Comment: Исправил код,посмотрите

Comment: @ArturHan, что-то не заработало (((